# Typescript Map instead of { [key: string]: SomeInterface }

Tags: typescript, dictionary, data-structures, interface, modeling

Given the following literal:

```
  user: UserConfigModel = {
    userId: 1,
    userName: "wayne",
    fullName: "Wayne Riesterer",
    email: "",
    modules: {
      skydiving: {
        moduleType: "Feature",
        name: "Skydiving",
        accessLevel: 1,
        urls: {
          details: "/skydiving/details",
          save: "/skydiving/save"
        }
      },
      paragliding: {
        moduleType: "Feature",
        name: "Paragliding",
        accessLevel: 1,
        urls: {
          details: "/paragliding/details"
        }
      },
    }
  };
```

and the following interfaces:

```
export interface UserConfigModel {
  userId: number;
  userName: string;
  fullName: string;
  email: string;
  modules: {[ moduleName: string]: ModuleConfigModel};
}

export interface ModuleConfigModel {
  moduleType: string;
  name: string;
  accessLevel: number;
  urls: { [ urlName: string]: string };
}
```

How can the following be converted to using Map:

```
modules: {[ moduleName: string]: ModuleConfigModel};
urls: { [ urlName: string]: string };
```

I have tried this with no success:

```
modules: Map<string, ModuleConfigModel>;
urls: Map<string, string>;
```

Help would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the `Record` type? Eg: `Record<string, ModuleConfigModel>` would be equivalent to your previous definition of `{[moduleName: string]: ModuleConfigModel}`.

Comment: @CRice, that worked perfectly. Thanks heaps! I've spent quite a few hours trying to work this one out.

Comment: @CRice, I haven't been able to find any documentation on the Record type. Can you please point me to some resource?

Comment: There isn't much afaik, but they talk about it a bit in their [2.1 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) and in the [handbook section on mapped types.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)